# Dapp on Ganache and Truffle but... what about Remix?

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, dapps, ganache

My dapp runs well with Ganache and Truffle but how to deploy with Remix and connect the contract to web GUI without abi?

I mean, i created a Dapp that runs really good on Ganache and i run the web interface and the node with `npm run dev`.

Now i want to deploy it using Remix, and i want to put all my js files and Index.html to my web server.

How can i do it without destroy all my code? is it possible?

Comment: You can deploy your smart contract using truffle or remix. Your frontend dapp just needs to use the deployed smart contract address and use an updated web3 provider to point to the network where you deployed the contract to.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your dapp without ganache, truffle, npm e.t.c. you can host your frontend to github pages. write a contract on online remix Ide,deploy it it to testnetwork. Get address and ABI, connect it to frontend and deploy frontend on GitHub pages and access dapp from website with metamask.

Comment: Ok, thanks but ... when i have ABI and address , where have i to use them? I think i have to modify the .js file so there is a problem because i really don't know how to use them.